# Power Query or R. Pivoting data and creating missing dates in between start and end dates

Tags: r, powerbi, dax, powerquery, project-management

I am building a staff utilisation dashboard.

I have a dataset with projects estimated start and end date. Each project is allocated to a project manager.  An assumption is that a project manager should dedicate an even number of hours to a project per day (4.2)

---

Project No  Start   End Owner   available hours to work on project per day
1   1/04/2020   30/07/2020  Eunice  4.2
2   1/04/2020   30/07/2020  Ayla    4.2
3   28/02/2020  30/05/2020  Martin  4.2
4   1/04/2020   30/10/2020  Eunice  4.2
5   1/05/2020   30/06/2020  Ayla    4.2
6   1/03/2020   30/06/2020  Martin  4.2
7   1/04/2020   30/06/2020  Eunice  4.2
8   1/04/2020   30/07/2020  Ayla    4.2
9   28/02/2020  30/05/2020  Martin  4.2
10  1/05/2020   30/06/2020  Eunice  4.2

---

I need to be able to show how much capacity and workload we have got at any given point of time at aggregate level

The visual that I am after is something like that:
[image: visual]

To build such visual the data should be in this layout:

Date    Project Name    Hours per day
1/04/2020   1   Eunice  4.2
2/04/2020   1   Eunice  4.2
3/04/2020   1   Eunice  4.2
…
30/07/2020  1   Eunice  4.2
1/04/2020   2   Ayla    4.2
2/04/2020   2   Ayla    4.2
3/04/2020   2   Ayla    4.2
4/04/2020   2   Ayla    4.2
…
29/07/2020  2   Ayla    4.2
30/07/2020  2   Ayla    4.2
….

Is there way to convert the original dataset into the final one that using PowerQuery or R? Or is there way to do that without creating missing rows with dates inbetween Start and End date of a project?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do that by creating a "list" of a ranges of values between two dates in Power Query:

Dates = { Number.From([Start])..Number.From([End]) }

Then, I expanded the list to new rows and creating duplicate lines with project id, names and hours for each day of a project.